# What's wrong with this code block?

Tags: java

I am trying to filter out some of the data from a List of Entity Objects. Here is my sample code:

```
List<Student> lstUniversalEvents = getAllStudentEvents(StudentID,startTime,endTime);
List<Student> lstTriggerEvents=null;

if(lstUniversalEvents.size()>0)
{
    for (Student event1 : lstUniversalEvents) 
    {
        if(strHighSchool.equals("true"))
        {
            if(event1.getClass().equals("HIGH_SCHOOL"))
            {
                lstTriggerEvents.add(event1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The line `lstTriggerEvents.add(event1);` is throwing a java.lang.NullPointerException.

Trouble-shooting, I found the following:

1. The `lstUniversalEvents` list has data.
2. condition `if(lstUniversalEvents.size()>0)`  was PASSED
3. condition `if(strHighSchool.equals("true"))` was PASSED
4. condition `if(event1.getClass().equals("HIGH_SCHOOL"))` was PASSED

So basically, it's failing to add the event to the new list lstTriggerEvents.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting `lstTriggerEvents` to something other than `null`.

```
List<Student> lstTriggerEvents = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

or, in Java 7+,

```
List<Student> lstTriggerEvents = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 4):

You never initialized `lstTriggerEvents`, it's still null.
Change the declaration to

```
List<Student> lstTriggerEvents=new ArrayList<Student>();
```

When you declare a variable you have to initialize it, otherwise the JVM assigns a default value. For reference types (like your list) that value is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize lstTriggerEvents list. It's null. Try

```
List<Student> lstTriggerEvents= new ArrayList<Student>
```